# Is it possible to hide few controls of an UpdatePanel when the page is getting loaded for the first time?

Tags: asp.net

I have a User control(ascx) that has an Update panel. When the page is getting loaded on some condition i want it to hide few of its controls of the UpdatePanel. Is it possible??

If any expert can help me out, i would really appreciate that!

thanks in advance!
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in your updatepanel's load event, set the Visible property of those controls to false. Alternatively, you could use the CSS style display to toggle their visibility.

You can also set these in the original page load if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying!! That was quick! I am new to programming.
Let me make this question bit more clear. My updatepanel has few div classes, tables,etc. On certain condition, it has to hide few of them. Or else, it has to show everything. It should depend on where this control is called from. Is that possible to load few instead of all. Hope you understand what i need. Thanks much for the patience.

Comment: The problem here is that i don't have all of them available to mark them false. I have radio buttons and labels for which i did. There are div classes in which there are some div classes. To make them invisible, which way do you think is the best? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you divs have IDs? You can set their Display value in Javascript. Or, you can wrap those divs to asp:Panel types if it's easier. Then, you can just work with the panel visible property.